# Combining files by column in bash with conditional

Tags: bash, awk, concatenation, paste

I would like to combine several `txt` files in bash by column. Each file have the name `File` as a pattern followed by a number. Thus, `File1.txt` `File2.txt` `File3.txt` and so on. Below 3 files to be used as example (but I have several).

File1:

```
######## infx infx infx
######## infx infx infx
####### infx infx 
probeset_id sample1 sample2 sample3
PR01           1       2       0
PR02           -1      2       0
PR03            2      1       1
PR04           1       2       1
PR05           2       0       1'
```

File 2:

```
######## infx infx infx
######## infx infx infx
probeset_id sample4 sample5 sample6
PR01           2       2       1
PR02           2      -1       0
PR03            2      1       1
PR04           1       2       1
PR05           0       0       1'
```

File 3:

```
# The dfn 
######## infx infx infx
######## infx infx infx
probeset_id samplen1 samplen2 samplen3
PR01           2       -1       1
PR02           1      -1       0
PR03            2      1       1
PR04           1       2       -1
PR05           0       2       1'
```

To finish with the follow output.txt:

```
 $ head output.txt
      probeset_id sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6 samplen1 samplen2 samplen3
    1        PR01       1       2       0       2       2       1        2       -1        1
    2        PR02      -1       2       0       2      -1       0        1       -1        0
    3        PR03       2       1       1       2       1       1        2        1        1
    4        PR04       1       2       1       1       2       1        1        2       -1
    5        PR05       2       0       1       0       0       1        0        2        1
```

ps. The number of lines with `##` can be different between the files. Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use next command

```
join <(grep -v "^#" file1) <(grep -v "^#" file2) | 
join - <(grep -v "^#" file3) | awk '{print (NR>1?NR-1:""), $0}'
```

you get

```
 probeset_id sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6 samplen1 samplen2 samplen3
1 PR01 1 2 0 2 2 1 2 -1 1
2 PR02 -1 2 0 2 -1 0 1 -1 0
3 PR03 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1
4 PR04 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 -1
5 PR05 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 2 1
```